# Dependency error installing Oracle Client SDK on Linux

Tags: linux, oracle

Trying to install Oracle Client and the SDK on Red Hat Linux EL6:

```
[~]: sudo rpm -ivh oracle-instantclient12.1-basiclite-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
   1:oracle-instantclient12.########################################### [100%]
```

That seemed to go ok.  But then trying to install the SDK...

```
[~]: sudo rpm -ivh oracle-instantclient12.1-devel-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm 
error: Failed dependencies:
    oracle-instantclient12.1-basic >= 12.1.0.2.0 is needed by oracle-instantclient12.1-devel-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64
```

Didn't I just install oracle-instantclient12.1-basiclite-12.1.0.2.0-1?

Comment: Yes, but that's not the package it asked for.

Comment: Ahhhhhh.  I went for Basic Lite instead of Basic.  Something tells me you've been here before!

Comment: It's a bit silly though - why is 'basiclite' not sufficient for the devel package if "Basic Light Package - Smaller version of the Basic package, with only English error messages and Unicode, ASCII, and Western European character set support"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Michael Hampton](https://serverfault.com/users/126632/michael-hampton) pointed out, I did not read the error message correctly.  I had installed the 'Basic Lite' Oracle Instant Client, whereas the SDK package (oracle-instantclient12.1-devel) was requiring the 'Basic' Oracle Instant Client.

My success below.  The sqlplus package went in ok after as well.

```
[~]: sudo rpm -ivh oracle-instantclient12.1-basic-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
   1:oracle-instantclient12.########################################### [100%]
[~]: sudo rpm -ivh oracle-instantclient12.1-devel-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
   1:oracle-instantclient12.########################################### [100%]
[~]: sudo rpm -ivh oracle-instantclient12.1-sqlplus-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm 
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
   1:oracle-instantclient12.########################################### [100%]
```